# Cross-compare several files with a diff tool

Tags: diff, comparison, file-comparison

Have anyone encountered the challenge of comparing several files with each other on a Mac/unix machine?

Consider a list of files 100.txt, 101.txt, 102.txt etc. in the same folder.

How can I cross-compare all these files to see 1) the percentage of text match between the files and, possibly, 2) a diff report between sets of files?

Comment: In Windows there is FC whitch you can use to compare differences between 2 txt files. Maybe by using a script with FC you can reach your goal.

Comment: Forgot to add, I'm a mac user

Comment: You would have to look for tools that can do comparisons on text files, especially such ones that can run from the command line and used in scripts...